# Context from Django Render Not Displaying Till Refresh?

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

I am using an AJAX call to POST a value to my views.
From my views I am finding the product based on the value(id) passed to my view. I add it to my invoice and apply it to my context which I render at the bottom of my view. The context will not be displayed until I refresh, but I can't have that. I am stuck.

```
...
elif request.is_ajax():
    product_id = request.POST.get('value')
    if product_id:
        product_info = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        new_invoice_product = InvoiceProduct.objects.create(invoice_product_set=product_info)
        invoice.attached_products.add(new_invoice_product)
        context['attached_products'] = invoice.attached_products.all()
...

return render(request, 'inventory/invoice_create.html', context)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't just re-render client's HTML DOM by your server directly.

Through DjangoTemplate Engine, it just render then respond with HTML itself. This means you can't update client's DOM with ajax unless you update root element, `<html>`. (and this will be as same as reloading page!)

So you may want to update DOM tree with some data, do with ajax call then update with `json`file only. If you use `JsonResponse`, then you can get it with AJAX response object.

Then What you have to do is NOT django template but JavaScript programming.

In your views.py, do like this:

```
# in your views.py
...
elif request.is_ajax():
    product_id = request.POST.get('value')
    if product_id:
    product_info = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    new_invoice_product = InvoiceProduct.objects.create(invoice_product_set=product_info)
    invoice.attached_products.add(new_invoice_product)
    context['attached_products'] = invoice.attached_products.all()
    # return render(request, 'inventory/invoice_create.html', context) # NOT render but do like this:
    return JsonResponse({
        'new_data': {
            'id': new_invoice_product.id
            # and other informations you want...
        }
    })
```

In your HTML, do like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    // in your HTML
    // guessing you're using jquery..
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function (json) {
        $('yourSelector').append(json['new_data']['id']);
    });
</script>
```

Remember, this code is just snippet not Fully working code. If you want to know further examples, take a look at link:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: Well the problem that I am not understanding is I am looping through in my template which should display the 'attached_products' which is a ManyToMany field in my invoice Model which attaches products to certain invoices. Will this still do so?

Comment: So concept is simple, "you can't re-write HTML on client side". django template engine only works with server-side rendering. If you use AJAX then it doesn't work. so you have to do client-side rendering with JS.
It doesn't relevant with MTM models as rendered HTML is just 'String' not real-python model.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Do you think my question is a relevant one to keep up?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Now just gotta reorganize things! Thanks!

Comment: @OhGreatOne Great to hear that :)

Comment: One more question...How would I take that `id` i returned in json and put it in a dynamic url?
Edit: ie. `{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}` which is what I used in my template for loop.

Comment: you don't need to get url by id that you response.

Comment: umm, what do you want exactly?

Comment: On each product that is generated through this ajax call, each one needs to have a link to a dynamic url in my urls.py which I pass in the product ID. I now am getting this ID as json from the ajax call.

Comment: @Beomi nearly everything you have said here is wrong. You certainly can use Ajax with Django templates and I can't understand why you would ay otherwise. You just need the Ajax callback to insert the rendered HTML into the DOM whereever you like.

Comment: I think just we're talking about different point :) As you said, surely questioner can use rendered template! but I thought update all of DOM is same cost as just reloading page. If origin question's code is seperationg template and then return it and put into HTML directly, it is okay. But what I want to saying is just "We can't use django template engine's syntax directly in front-end side".